# Google Drive: Make Folder/All Files in Folder Available Offline

Tags: google-drive

I'm using the Google Drive app on the latest Android system, Android 11. I can make files, specifically PDFs, available offline by long pressing and clicking `Make Available Offline`. Further, if I select two PDFs, both of which are not yet available offline, then I have this option.
As such, I was able to initially select all files in a folder and pick `Make Available Offline`.

The issues is that I add to the folder regularly. If I select two files in the folder, one of which *is* available offline and the other *is not*, then the `Make Available Offline` option is not there. Currently I have some ~290 PDFs which are available offline and ~10 which are not. I do want all to be available offline, as I never know when I'll need them. But I don't want to manually go through and add them all.

> **TL;DR.** Is there a way to make all files in a folder, or just simply the folder, available offline?
>
> This needs to work if the folder currently contains a mixture: some available offline already and some not.

I would even accept the following horribly inefficient solution:

- remove the 'available offline' property from all files in the folder;
- select all files and `Make Available Offline`.

However, removing the property from all seems just as hard as adding it.